# Using Appium 5.0.0-beta01 & Selenium 4.0.1-Not able to launch android driver using AppiumLocalService()

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium-android, parallel-execution

I am trying to achieve parallelism in the android automation framework. Can anyone please guide me on how to achieve it, as I am unaware of it and this is my very own attempt.
Please suggest how to achieve parallel execution of Test cases in .NET android automation framework for nightly automation using **"Appium 5.0.0-beta01 version and Selenium 4.0.1."**

Need help with the implementation of 2 things:

**1. To start multiple Appium servers on any available free port via automation and android driver instantiation on them.**

I have implemented using Class **AppiumLocalService** but the application is not able to launch android driver with error **“OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'The session identified by c6dc0b0d-0d71-40cd-aa7b-7f4fea66c5f2 is not known”:**

Please find below args I have passed to launch the driver:

```
var args = new OptionCollector().AddArguments(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("–base-path", “/wd/hub”));

_appiumLocalService = new AppiumServiceBuilder().WithIPAddress(“127.0.0.1”).UsingAnyFreePort().WithArguments(args).Build();

_appiumLocalService.Start();
AndroidDriver _androidDriver = new AndroidDriver(_appiumLocalService, appiumoptions, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
```

**2.To start multiple emulators programmatically and to execute parallel test suits on each emulator and their integration with Appium server instances.**
Did not find AndroidDebugBridge class in c# which allows to launch emulator programmatically.